# read from file return empty string with no errors

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get a string from a file using the code below:

```
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public String useRawResFile(){
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.elwords));
    LineNumberReader lnr=new LineNumberReader(is);
    String randomWord="";
    int numLines=0;
    Random r = new Random();
    lnr.setLineNumber(r.nextInt(numLines));
    try{
        randomWord = lnr.readLine();

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return randomWord;
}

public String selRandomWord(){
    String randomWordSelection="";

    if(isExternalStorageReadable()) {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(path, "elwords.dat");

        try{
            if(file.exists()) {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                LineNumberReader lnr=new LineNumberReader(fr);
                int numLines=0;
                Random r = new Random();
                lnr.setLineNumber(r.nextInt(numLines));
                try{
                    randomWordSelection = lnr.readLine();

                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    useRawResFile();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        useRawResFile();
    }
    return randomWordSelection;
}
```

I'm using the selRandomWord() method in onCreate, but the String I get is null. I'm not getting any error, and the file has words(one for each line). Is something wrong or missign in the above code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely seeing this issue because you are failing the check to  `if (file.exists())`and then returning the default value of `randomWordSelection`. Try out the suggestion of the previous answer (and make sure to check the obvious things-- that the filename is correct, for instance!).

The main reason for my response is that I noticed another issue in the code. In both sections of code where you refer to `numLines`, you set `numLines` to 0 by default, then proceed to call `r.nextInt(numLines)` without altering the value of `numLines`. The `nextInt(int n)` method returns a random int between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive). If n is 0, what will it return? In fact, it throws an error in this case! In short, you will want to set `numLines` to some sensible value (the number of lines in the file) before using it to generate a random value.

Comment: I set the numlines number and I updated the manifest with permission to read/write external storage and after that the app stuck and I get errors about "Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 16% free..." forever.

Answer (score 0):

Instad of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`
use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Gives you the full path the SDCard. You can then do normal File I/O operations using standard Java.

For ex-

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath  ();
String fileName = "myFile.txt";
File f = new File(baseDir + File.Separator + fileName);
 FileInputStream fiStream = new FileInputStream(f);
  byte[] bytes;
  fiStream.read(bytes); 
   fiStream.close();
```

I hope this will help you...